# Power Apps upload multiple files to Sharepoint Library via

Tags: sharepoint-online, attachments, powerapps-canvas, office-365-groups

i have problem with upload multiple files via `HttpRequest` to `Sharepoint` Library.
In `Power App` have `AttachmentControll_1` with Atributes `MaxAttachmentSize` 10000, `MaxAttachments` 200.

`Button code:`

```
ForAll(
AttachmentControll_1.Attachments,
Office365Groups.HttpRequest(
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxx/drives/yyyy/root:/"& ThisRecord.Name &":/content",
    "PUT",
    ThisRecord.Value
  )
);
```

When i add 10 files to `AttachmentControll_1` and press the button. Sometimes upload 3 - 5 files, but never all files.

Is possible to add `Delay` to code ? Or how to figure out to get upload all files in `AttachmentControll_1`

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had many projects with the requirement of uploading documents to SP libraries. We've always used a Power Automate flow triggered from the app. You can pass the document as parameter.
[This video from Shane Young](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UeRzfPo8RE) explains how it works.